# How to change the directory for composer self-update --update-keys

Tags: php, composer-php

Using composer I try to change the directory for composer self-update --update-keys

Because it always shows up the Exception:

```
[ErrorException] file_put_contents(/var/www/webxx/.composer/keys.dev.pub): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

All the posts which propose sudo and chmod 777 do not help because it s a managed server and I do not have access to the HOME DIR and please let's skip this long long discussion why in this case a user does not have write access to his own home dir. It s a debian with a confixx:)

What I did via config in the composer.json is to change all dirs I can think of including of course the "home" and listing the config tells me it worked. But still it uses the

> /var/www/webxx/.composer/

The question is how to change this directory for composer self-update --update-keys without being root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define where Composer keeps it's files by setting the `COMPOSER_HOME` environment variable to the path you want.

Link: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Not completely understandable that to change the "home" in the json.config does not work for the keys, but the to change to env help